# Can't get official bnlearn tutorial on "Creating custom fitted Bayesian networks" to run

Tags: r, bnlearn

I'm looking at the official tutorial [here](http://www.bnlearn.com/examples/custom/). I copied their code exactly but RStudio is giving me error messages for the lines `, , B = GOOD` (error message: `unexpected ',' in ","`) and `dfit` (error message: `object dfit not found`). Here's the exact code I copied:

```
# install.packages("bnlearn")
library(bnlearn)

cptA = matrix(c(0.4, 0.6), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("LOW", "HIGH")))
#cptA
cptB = matrix(c(0.8, 0.2), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("GOOD", "BAD")))
#cptB

cptC = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.8)
dim(cptC) = c(2, 2, 2)
dimnames(cptC) = list("C" = c("TRUE", "FALSE"), "A" =  c("LOW", "HIGH"), "B" = c("GOOD", "BAD"))
#cptC

, , B = GOOD

net = model2network("[A][B][C|A:B]")
dfit = custom.fit(net, dist = list(A = cptA, B = cptB, C = cptC))
dfit
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial put the output together with the code and you copied one line of it by accident. You can look at a similar example in the documentation of the package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bnlearn/bnlearn.pdf). 
It should be:

```
library(bnlearn)

cptA = matrix(c(0.4, 0.6), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("LOW", "HIGH")))
#cptA
cptB = matrix(c(0.8, 0.2), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("GOOD", "BAD")))
#cptB

cptC = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.8)
dim(cptC) = c(2, 2, 2)
dimnames(cptC) = list("C" = c("TRUE", "FALSE"), "A" =  c("LOW", "HIGH"), "B" = c("GOOD", "BAD"))

cptC
# , , B = GOOD
# 
# A
# C       LOW HIGH
# TRUE  0.5  0.4
# FALSE 0.5  0.6
# 
# , , B = BAD
# 
# A
# C       LOW HIGH
# TRUE  0.3  0.2
# FALSE 0.7  0.8


net = model2network("[A][B][C|A:B]")
cfit = custom.fit(net, dist = list(A = cptA, B = cptB, C = cptC))
```